# Use JAX-RS and JPA with Tomcat without catch-finally

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, jax-rs

We are working with JAX-RS and JPA. We use methods that have the following structure (details omitted):

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResultObject saveById(   @PathParam("id") BigInteger id, 
SomeObject someObject) {

    entityManager = EMF.obtainEntityManager();

    try {

      .. start transaction

      .. write all information to the database

      .. commit transaction

      .. return ResultObject
    } catch ( Exception exception) {

      .. rollback transaction

      .. return ResultObject together with an appropriate error
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }           
}
```

Is there a ‘best’ way to avoid repeating the catch and finally on every JAX-RS method that we create? Using filters?
Our service provicer only supports Tomcat. No Glassfish or other containers.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would move implementation to different service that would be called by REST service. REST should be a type of your API. And logic should be in different service.

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResultObject saveById( @PathParam("id") BigInteger id, SomeObject someObject) {
    ResultObject resultObject = new ResultObject();
    ResultType res = someService.saveById(id, someObject)
    // do something with res
    return resultObject ;
}
```

And then in SomeService would implement some abstract class that could implement a logic of transaction.

```
public abstract class AbstractService {
    protected void startTransaction() {
        //...
    }
    protected void endTransaction() {
        //...
    }
}

public class SomeService extends AbstractService {
   public ResultType saveById(BigInteger id, SomeObject someObject) {
       startTransaction();
       // your logic
       endTransaction();
   }
}
```

There is also better way. You could use Spring Framework if you know it. 
In that solution you annotate SomeService (or method in that class) with @Transactional.

```
@Transactional
public class SomeService {
   public ResultType saveById(BigInteger id, SomeObject someObject) {

       // your logic

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. We have been thinking about it. At the moment our services-layer consists of the JAX-RS annotated methods themselves. 
Behind this services layer we have a component-layer doing all the business logic and database access. The JAX-RS annotated methods are pretty small already (an average of maybe 5-10 statements). 
We do not know if implementing an extra services layer between the JAX-RS methods and the component-layer (just to get rid of the try-catch-finally construction in the JAX-RS methods) would be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Create EntityManger in a filter

Eg:-

```
public class EntityManagerFilter implements Filter {


  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
      /
      em = EntityManagerFactoryUtil.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
     //
      EntityManagerUtil.ENTITY_MANAGERS.set(em);
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
      EntityManagerUtil.ENTITY_MANAGERS.remove();
      //

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      //

    } finally {
      try {
        if (em != null) {
          em.close();
          //
        };
      } catch (Throwable t) {
       //
      }
    }
  }

  public void init(FilterConfig config) {
    destroy();
    initEntityManagerFactory();
  }

  private void initEntityManagerFactory() {
    EntityManagerFactoryUtil.entityManagerFactory =
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistanceUnitName");
   //

  }

  public void destroy() {
   //
    try {
      if (EntityManagerFactoryUtil.entityManagerFactory != null) {
        EntityManagerFactoryUtil.entityManagerFactory.close();
      };
    } catch (Exception t) {
     /
  }
}

public class EntityManagerUtil {



 public static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> ENTITY_MANAGERS = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

  /** Returns a fresh EntityManager */
  public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return ENTITY_MANAGERS.get();
  }

}

public class EntityManagerFactoryUtil {

  public static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
}
```